# Different server output in Firefox vs Chrome, why?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, server, header

Running IIS 10 on Server 2019, fully patched. I have the following .aspx webpage code:

```
For Each var As String In Request.ServerVariables
  Response.Write(var &" "& Request(var))
Next
```

Why does Firefox purposefully (apparently) ignore the **HTTP_SEC_FETCH_** server headers while Chrome happily displays them?

Firefox 69.0.1 output:

```
...
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  1
```

Chrome 77.0.3865.90 output:

```
...
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  1
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE navigate
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER ?1
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE none
```

This is *server* output so why does Firefox ignore that data? Or am I not understanding how server variables work? The output above is at the very end of the list.

Comment: Same behavior in Firefox 70.0.1 (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Chrome is (once again) ahead of Firefox in following RFC and various miscellaneous stuff. In this case it is a thing called "Fetch Metadata Request Headers" per https://www.w3.org/TR/fetch-metadata/ and is inserted into the fetch request by the browser. Now I know. (And knowing is half the battle!)